# Importing data from personal geodatabase to Excel and/or Access?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, personal-geodatabase

My dataset it much more than what ArcGIS 10.3 can export to a .xls file so I was told that I could write the data to a personal geodatabase which I then could import to excel and/or access. I tried to use Table to geodatabase but it does not seem to work. When I try and import the data into excel for example as access database I dont get the information from the attribute tables. I just get things like GDB ItemRelationship types with sub categories such as forward lable, backward lable etc... I just want a copy of the attribute table! Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What were the precise steps you performed and the exact results that you achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can export your table to CSV and open your CSV file in Excel. To do that load the file into ArcMAp, then `open the attribute table -> Go to table options -> Export`. When you select the target path to save your table, change the Save as type from "File and Personal geodatabase Table" to "CSV". Thne open the CSV file from Excel.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought about doing it that way. It seems excel 2016 cant do more than just over 1million cells so I cant use it :P

Comment: If you have MS Access, then you can open your mdb file directly without conversion.

Answer (score 1):

An "empty" geodatabase contains a set of tables used to manage the complexity of a geographic database. One of the tables will be your attribute table, so that you don't have to worry about the other tables.

Alternatively, you can convert your table to csv and then import the csv in another application, or you can build an [OLE DB connection to your access database](http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/connecting-to-a-microsoft-access-database.htm)  to export your table directly into Access (non personnal gdb) file. In both cases you will use TableToTable tool.